# How do I re-render a react component after a sibling component finishes an API request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to update a sibling element once a react component loads. Using the example below, I would like to change "The data has not yet rendered" to "Hello world" once PopupTable is loaded.

My issue is, if I try to change the state during a render() call I get a warning telling me not to, what is the proper way to handle this?

```
class PopupBase extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    The data has not yet rendered.
                </div>
                <DataProvider endpoint="products/ajax/get_products_from_pickle" render={data =>
                    // Once the code get to here, I want to update the div above
                    <PopupTable data={data}/>
                }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class DataProvider extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
    state = {
        data: [],
        loaded: false,
        placeholder : this.props.placeholder
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(this.props.endpoint)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    return this.setState({placeholder: "Something went wrong"});
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => this.setState({data: data, loaded: true}));
    }

    render() {
        const {data, loaded, placeholder} = this.state;
        return loaded ? this.props.render(data) : <div>{placeholder}</div>;
    }
}

export default DataProvider;
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is changing your code to:

```js
class PopupBase extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <DataProvider          
     endpoint="products/ajax/get_products_from_pickle"
     render={data =>
           <div>             
                <div>
                    The data has { data ? "" : "not yet" } rendered.
                </div>                                    
                <PopupTable data={data}/> 
           </div>    
        }/>);
    }
}
```

A better approach is to extract the data loading logic into a Higher Order Function. So you will have a pure react component that renders purely based on the props. And another 'wrapper' component (i.e. the `DataProvider`) that loads data from API and feeds the `data` prop to the visual component.

Comment: This issue with this is the API call is long running, so I want the <div> to actually say "Loading". If I put the <div> as part of the callback, the user won't see the loading message until after it's loaded.

Comment: @superdee, If you want to show loading, you can pass the `isLoading` status to the render function alone with the `data`. Or implicitly, you can assume that if the `data` prop is `undefined`, it is loading.